# can't bind to 'sticky' since it isn't a known property of 'kendo-grid-column'

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

in kendo grid - angular version

```
<kendo-grid-column [field]="col.field"
        [width]="col.width" 
        [headerClass]="col.field === 'active' ? 'text-left' : ''"
        [sortable]="(col.field === 'category' || col.field === 'delete') ? false : true"
        [sticky]="(col.field === 'active') ? true : false">
   >
```

im trying to implement the sticky option, based on the below link descriptions

https://feedback.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/1360640-allow-to-lock-columns-to-the-right-side

https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/columns/sticky/?_ga=2.73870674.1788049368.1626181569-1673404474.1541581695

getting that issue

Comment: to use this feature, in my project  i update these libs
 "@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "5.2.1",
"@progress/kendo-angular-pdf-export": "3.0.1",
"@progress/kendo-angular-label": "3.0.3",

Answer (score 1):

As you pointed out in your comment, you had to update to a more recent package of `@progress/kendo-angular-grid`. `sticky` was introduced in version 5 I believe (I know it wasn't working in `@progress/kendo-angular-grid@4.8.4`, but was working in `5.2.1`--it's unfortunate that the Kendo docs don't seem to offer an option to select a version to view documentation about; they obviously wrote that documentation in that past, it should be accessible).

Additionally, assuming you're in an enterprise environment or just pay for licensing on your personal project, you may want to follow [these steps](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/my-license/) to set up the license that is a new requirement since version 5 (you'll need to be signed in to your Telerik account and also have purchased a license to be able to access the part of the page that generates the license key file to download). Currently the only repercussion of running these packages without a license is a bunch of annoying warnings in the dev console, but Telerik is still deciding if they want to take away some or possibly all of their library's functionality when a valid license is not present.

NOTE: "Valid license" means that the version of Kendo that you're using was released while that license was/is still active, it does not need to be regularly maintained until you want to upgrade the packages again.

Some additional information on the new licensing process is available [here](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/introducing-license-keys-kendo-ui-for-angular) for those interested.